# How to set maven property depending on module existing or not?

Tags: maven

lets say I have a multi-module maven project. Let there be project `main1` with the two modules `sub1` and `sub1`. Now I have other multi-module projects with the same structure: Let they be called `main2` and `main3`, also having the sub-modules `sub1` and `sub1` (in this case, the artifactId is the same, but the groupId's are different). The parent pom of `main2` and `main3` is always the one of `main1`, which makes `main1` sort of a standard model for the projects.

Now, it might be that a project, let it be `main3`, also has a module `special`, which does not exist in project `main1`.

As `main1` serves as configuration master for all the projects (as parent project): Is there a way to define a property in `main1` so that it has one value in all modules `sub1`, `sub2` and so on but a different value in a module if the module is called `special`?

I tried some tricks with profiles (trying to activate a profile depending on the modules name), but nothing really worked.

Thank you,
Thorsten

Edit: I am not so familiar with GitHub (or git at all ;-) ), but I can provide some sample projects as zip file on my google drive: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3HaXNowsauHdEZuc1RlRXZSLUk

Comment: Can you make an example project on github or so? I'm not sure I understand what you are trying?

Comment: Done. Sort of ;-)